# URI codeigniter library not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm just learning codeigniter, and I seem to have run into something that is a little strange. I'm using the URI routing feature but need to get the URI segments of the re-routed URI.

This is one of the routes:

```
$route['content'] = "site/display/main template/content";
```

and when visiting `http://lipsum.localhost/content` it loads the controller, but it won't let me use the URI class:

```
class Site extends Controller {

    function display($template, $page) {

        echo "display<br>";

        $this->load->library('uri');
        echo $this->uri->rsegment(1, 0)."<br>";
        echo $this->uri->rsegment(2, 0)."<br>";
        echo $this->uri->rsegment(3, 0)."<br>";
        echo $this->uri->rsegment(4, 0)."<br>";

    }

}
```

when I visit the page, it just displays

```
display
0
0
0
0
```

Basically this code should load a template and then pass `$page` to it so it can load a section of a website. So 'content' might use 'main template' as the template, and then pass 'content' to it as the page to load. But I also want to be able to pass '/products/whatever' to it, etc -- so I want to cycle through the URI segments to get the full "path" to the page. How can I make it work? And, why is what I have not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting rid of the space in "main template", use an underscore or camelCase it together to "mainTemplate". I can't remember the last time I saw a space in any kind of route or url.

Answer (score 0):

to do that you add custom routes to your /app/config/routes.php file.

```
$route['title-of-the-page'] = "<controller>/<method>";
```